# Use .find() to get all descendants of an element but not their descendants

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some html where elements are nested to create an accordion effect. Something similar to:

```
<span class="container">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <span class="container">
        <div class="item">1.a</div>
        <span class="container">
            <div class="item">1.a.1</div>
        </span>
    </span>
</span>
```

I need to use `$('.container').find('.item').each()` to create a hierarchy where 1.a becomes a child of 1 and 1.a.1 becomes a child of 1.a. The issue that I have is that 1.a.1 also becomes a child of 1 because 1.a.1 is a descendant of 1.

Theoretically there could also be 1.b or 1.c, etc. so I do need to find all descendants, not just the first one, but I don't want to find descendants of descendants.

Is there a simple jQuery way to do this?

.children() doesn't work for my specific case because there are more nested containers and whatnot in the actual HTML I'm in.

Comment: You can use `children('.item')` or `find('> .item')`, however your first selector is going to return all containers, including nested ones.  So going off of a global selector like that, you are still going ot return all the items.

Comment: You could `$('.container').first()` to get just the top container before getting only it's nested items.

Comment: @Taplar I should have thought to mention this, but the reason I am using .find() instead of .children() is because in my HTML the .item elements are not direct children of the .container elements. I wrote a mockup HTML so I didn't paste 50 lines that I erroneously figured were irrelevant.

Comment: Then you will have to select the specific container, find the nested items, and then filter out those whose closest container is not the desired container.

Comment: Are you looking for something in the lines of [this](https://jsfiddle.net/7jxuowqL/)?

Answer (score 0):

I've written the functionality here. The idea is that you're looking for all descendants with the `item` class. Then you remove all those elements from the list that have an ancestor with the `item` class. That ancestor still needs to be a descendant from the container (or your element starting point).

```
var container = $('.container');
var descendants = container.find('.item');
var res = [];
descendants.each(function() {
    let parents = $(this).parents();
    for (let i = 0; i < parents.length; i++) {
        //console.log('p: ' + $(parents[i]).text());
        if (container.html() == $(parents[i]).html()) {
            //no ancestors with the `item` class found, this is a good one.
            res.push($(this));
            break;
        }
        if ($(parents[i]).hasClass('item')) {
            //if an ancestor with the same class has been found
            //it cannot be kept
            break;
        }
    }
});
console.log(descendants);
console.log(res);
```

I created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/93tu16bm/) to test

Comment: `$(parents[i])` is an anti-pattern.  You are breaking the element out of the jQuery result stack, and then creating a new jQuery object with just the one element.  Use `.eq(i)` to avoid that.

Comment: Also instead of making an off site fiddle to show the working code, make a runnable snippet *on site*.